# Mingw GCC cross compilation for windows XP

Tags: mingw, windows-xp

I need to compile a DLL on Windows 10 which will need to be usable on Windows XP.

The code compiles using Mingw GCC (and not using MSVC) and I don't know which version of mingw to use.

Is mingw GCC still compatible with windows XP (if yes does it need specific flags during compilation)?

If not, is there somewhere an information indicating on which version the windows XP support was dropped (I could not find any informations in the changelog)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Windows XP is no longer supported or updated by Microsoft itself and should be considered a security risk if you still use it.

To compile for older Windows versions with MinGW you need to define `_WIN32_WINNT` to an older version for (`0x0501` for Windows XP) when compiling your application as well as all of it's dependencies, including the standard library provided by MinGW.

So in essence you need a MinGW compiler that was itself built to support Windows XP and build your application and any libraries it may depend upon with it.

Comment: Your Winlibs work is amazing. But your first paragraph causes me itching. Microsoft actually stopped supporting it. This does not mean that many customers have ceased to use it. So we continue to support our customers in a operating system that is no longer supported. I assure you that we supported our customer in DOS when Windows 7 had already come out.

Comment: I still have one customer who is still using MS-DOS today! So I get your point.
Unfortunately quite some libraries are starting to use features not available in Windows XP, so it's just getting harder and harder building the development environment with Windows XP support. For LLVM it's not even possible at all.